# Romanised Japanese as a System Language

Tags: language-support, system-language

I'm currently trying to learn Japanese and people say the best way to learn a language is to immerse yourself in it, I was hoping that it was possible to learn romanised Japanese before trying to work out how to read the Hiragana and Katakana but it seems a romanised version of Japanese on ubuntu as a system language is hard to find. Is anyone aware of one existing or am I better off learning the Hiragana and Katakana?

Comment: I highly doubt such a thing would exist. It's a tough enough job having all the UI translated to Japanese (using kanji or kana as appropriate), romanised versions would be impractical.

Answer (score 2):

This would require a Latin script translation package. Unfortunately, one does not exist for Japanese, and would need to be created. An appropriate locale definition for such a language pack would be `ja@latin` if you wish to take on the task of creating one.